# minimum price of multiple supplier on same item with supplier name

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables

1. Inquiry
2. Supplier Quotation.

In supplier quotation table there is multiple supplier quoted value on same Inquiry,
i used the following query to get the minimum price of each supplier, i get the minimum price but there is problum on Supplier id(s_id).

```
SELECT E.enq_detail_id,E.modelno,
       E.qty,min(S.us_dollor_per1000) as minimum,
       S.s_id 
FROM enquiry_details as E 
LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier_quotation as S 
       ON E.enq_detail_id=S.enq_detail_id 
WHERE E.enq_id=15 
GROUP BY s.enq_detail_id`
```

i get the minimum value is ok but the S.s_id(supplier Id) is wrong as shown below screenshot.so please help me
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL allows you to select non-aggregate fields that are not included in the `GROUP BY`. In this case the results are non-determinate.

This is the case for the query you have written, which needs to include the supplier id in the `GROUP` BY clause.

Heres a good link explaining this issue with some worked examples:
http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

With Aggregate queries, my approach to ensure the query is readable and correct is to split the aggregation query away from any additional querying you need using subqueries.

Heres two example queries. A few column names don't quite match the original question but its roughly correct.

1) Select the best quote for all suppliers for a specific enquiry

```
SELECT * 
FROM enquiry_details E
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT enq_detail_id,
    supplier_id,
    MIN(us_dollar_per1000)
FROM supplier_quotation
WHERE enq_detail_id = 1
GROUP BY enq_detail_id, supplier_id
) best_quotes
ON best_quotes.enq_detail_id = E.id
WHERE E.`id` = 1
```

2) Select the very best quote across all suppliers for a specific enquiry

```
SELECT * 
FROM enquiry_details E
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT enq_detail_id,
    MIN(us_dollar_per1000)
FROM supplier_quotation
WHERE enq_detail_id = 1
GROUP BY enq_detail_id
) best_quotes
ON best_quotes.enq_detail_id = E.id
WHERE E.`id` = 1
```

Comment: thanks for responding when i use the S_id in group by then the items are dublicated?

Comment: I was assuming you wanted the best quote for each supplier - hence the duplicates? I've added two queries showing best per supplier and best overall. Any use?